# Problems with typealias swift

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication, type-alias

Hey i have a code that uses a typealias so that it will be able to send an error code to the user when they do not register correctly though my type alias doesn't work and it gives me the problem that my class suddenly becomes an error type when i use the type alias can someone pls tell me why this happens.

my code

```
import Foundation    
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth


typealias Completion = (errMsg: String?, data: AnyObject?) -> Void 

class AuthenticationDatabase{


    var database = Database()


    func register(user: [UITextField], onComplete: Completion?)-> String{
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: user[0].text, password:user[1].text) { (user, error) in
            if(error != nil){
                self.handleFirebaseError
            }
        }



    }

    func Login(UserInfo: [String]){

    }
    func logOut(){


    }
    func handleFirebaseError(error: NSError, onComplete:Completion?){
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error.code){
            switch (errorCode){
            case .errorCodeInvalidEmail:
            onComplete?(errMsg: "Invalid Email", data: nil)
            break
            case .errorCodeWrongPassword:
            onComplete?(errMsg: "invalid Password", data: nil)
            break
            default:
                onComplete?(errMsg: "There was a problem Authenticating. Try again.",data: nil)
            }
        }
    }





}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3+ the parameter labels in closures are omitted

```
typealias Completion = (String?, AnyObject?) -> Void
```

(It's highly recommended to use `Any` rather than `AnyObject`)

and call it

```
onComplete?("Invalid Email", nil)
```

Comment: but I whant the invalid email part to be an errormesage not the static invalid email thing

Comment: @J.Doe2 How is email static? You can pass anything on every call.

Comment: Once again, there are no parameter labels in closures, please get used to it.

Comment: I have a function that I call handlefirebaseerror that is supposed to send the error that I get from firebase back to the viewcontroller so I can use the message to show it for the user when he puts an error in registration so I mean I need to get message with a named variable do I not?

Comment: You don't. The string message is relevant, the label is not.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Completion` to

```
typealias Completion = (_ errMsg: String?, _ data: AnyObject?) -> Void
```

**OR**

```
typealias Completion = (String?, AnyObject?) -> Void
```

Comment: Does anyone have a tutorial on typealiases that is food so I can learn then?^^:)